# Can I use two colons in a sentence?

Tags: punctuation, writing-style, colons

Can I use two colons in a sentence? A typical example would be something like the following:

> Note: I have substantial experience with the following languages: Python, Java, C++, and Perl.

I have often wanted to write something similar but have been forcing rewrites in order to get around using two colons in the same sentence. The general pattern is:

> Note: [sentence with a colon].

Is this use of two colons acceptable?

---

(This question is similar but distinct from [Can I use a colon twice in one sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/132434/can-i-use-a-colon-twice-in-one-sentence) due to that question's focus on colons and lists.)

Comment: Well the second colon is misused anyway so you shouldn't be trying to emulate it. Two colons in one sentence are very indigestible.

Comment: Acceptable to whom? Using it in a programming blog is probably fine. Using it in a scholarly paper on grammar, maybe not.

Comment: @KevinWorkman: That seems like an answer?

Comment: @MrHen Not really. It's asking you for more information. What context are you in here? I don't think this is really standard grammar anyway, so it's going to depend on the rules of wherever you're publishing. I will say that even if it is "legal", the other thing to consider is how easy it is to read. I would guess that most people would find two colons harder to read than splitting it up.

Comment: @KevinWorkman: I don't have further context. I am asking if-and-when using colons this way would be appropriate.

Comment: @TheMathemagician: The least prescriptive 'rule' I've come across allowing the use of a colon is 'used to introduce what follows'. If I can read the pre-edited OP correctly, the second colon wouldn't warrant a 'misused' per se.

Comment: I doubt you're going to be able to find an explicit listing of when this is okay and when it's not. It's going to depend on the sentence, the context, the reader, etc. Even if you get an answer saying it's okay, that doesn't mean it's okay everywhere. Even if you get an answer saying it's okay in a programming publication, that doesn't mean that every sentence in this format is okay in every programming publication.

Comment: I don't think anybody is going to flag it down as being horribly incorrect grammar. But the question you need to ask is: is it immediately obvious to all of your readers, or are half of them going to stumble and need to re-read the sentence? You can offset some of this uncertainty stylistically (making the note: part bold or italicized, for example), but it's not really a question of grammar.

Comment: Lists that have something like *as follows* or *the following* before them are expected to use a colon. [Here are some references](http://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=%22the+following%22+colon+list&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest).

Answer (score 3):

> Note: I have only minimal experience with most of the languages below: I find the ideas behind them fascinating, but claim no expertise in them, so please point out any corrections and errors.

In the original example (pre-edit), the second colon is used wrongly, and should be replaced by either a full-stop/period or a semi-colon.

> Note: I have only minimal experience with most of the languages below. I find the ideas behind them fascinating, but claim no expertise in them, so please point out any corrections and errors.

Using colons is explained well [here](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/colons.asp). The example above uses "Note:" which is perfectly acceptable, but the second usage does not fit with any of the rules. You would expect the sentence "I have only minimal experience with most of the languages below" to be followed by a colon if you then went on to list the languages, but your example does not follow this structure.

EDIT: In response to Peter's comment, a sentence such as

> Note: I have substantial experience with the following languages: Python, Java, C++, and Perl.

Seems perfectly acceptable using two colons.

Comment: But suppose you wanted to say: *"Note: I have substantial experience with the following languages: Python, Java, C++, and Perl."* Would that be acceptable?

Comment: Only the EDIT portion of your answer is relevant to my question. I updated my question to remove the misused colon and replace it with the example Peter used. Hope that clears things up a bit. :)

Comment: This answer is incorrect when it alleges that the second colon is used wrongly.  Lists introduced by *the following* are correctly punctuated by a colon leading up to them.

Comment: @tchrist The answer originally referred to the sentence in the paragraph I quoted, which had no list - it read "Note: I have only minimal experience with most of the languages below: I find the ideas behind them fascinating, but claim no expertise in them, so please point out any corrections and errors."

Answer (score 2):

Everything before the colon must be a independent clause ([1 Reference among others](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jrolduvqhW8)).  "Note" is not explicitly an independent clause, the subject is in the imperative (you) and "note" is being used as a verb.  I would suggest changing it to the following:

> ***Please [this explicitly makes note a verb]*** note: I have substantial experience with the following languages: Python, Java, C++, and Perl.