# Writing a list with a description of each item -- Formal Writing [Research Paper]

Tags: punctuation, colons

I am trying to write the following sentence:

> "There are some objectives we cannot miss in any visualization
>   library, which are: performance: high-level abstraction may
>   limit the user’s ..., debugging: trial and error is a
>   fundamental part ..."

I kinda feel I have improper use of the colon **"which are:"** since I have a second colon describing the performance in **"performance: high-level ..."**

I have checked this proposed [approach](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/162840/can-i-use-two-colons-in-a-sentence). However, I have no suggests of how to apply it on my case.

Comment: Is a real bulleted list out of the question?

Comment: Oh no, not a bulleted list. I mean the regular English list in writing (i.e. Countries are: USA, Canada, and KSA).

Comment: What I meant was, a bulleted list would easily allow a colon in each entry. Is that not possible here? Otherwise, you may need to consider dashes.

Comment: Oh, gotcha. No, it is not really possible. Would you please illustrate how are dashes may be used?

Comment: Is it not possible to write this as a short paragraph?  It seems like a lot of information for a single sentence. I would keep your sentence as a simple list 'which are: _performance_, _debugging_...'.  Then follow up with a paragraph that defines those terms, one sentence for each keyword.  Italicize the keywords in the paragraph body to remind the reader that you are making a list of important definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best course of action is probably a bulleted list, which will easily allow a colon in each entry:

> There are some objectives we cannot miss in any visualization library, which are:
>
> - performance: high-level abstraction may limit the user’s ...,
> - debugging: trial and error is a fundamental part ...

However, if that's not possible, then dashes might be a possibility:

> There are some objectives we cannot miss in any visualization library, which are: performance —high-level abstraction may limit the user’s ...; debugging — trial and error is a fundamental part ...

Note the use of semi-colons to separate the list entries, which is a standard use. Within each item, you can then use "lesser" punctuation like dashes or commas (although commas aren't suitable in this particular case because they create something akin to a run-on sentence).